# After a 500 response no requests are sent again until process is restarted

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I am using Polly to implement request retries. However, after a 500 response is returned for a request, not only does Polly not send a request when it retries but no requests are sent at all until the process is restarted. Instead Polly just waits until there is a timeout. The following is the code:

```
var timeoutPolicy = TimeoutPolicy
    .TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(c => c.GetTimeout() ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); //timeout para cada intento

var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() //tirado por la TimeoutPolicy
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) });

var policyHandler = new PolicyHandler(Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, timeoutPolicy));
```

How can I fix the code such that Polly actually sends the request when it retries after a 500 and also for following requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the following [issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/642)

This is how I fixed it:

```
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() //tirado por la TimeoutPolicy
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] 
      { 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) 
      }, 
      onRetry: (x, _) =>
      {
          //dispose response when retrying
          x.Result?.Dispose();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that the application crash is not related to these policies.

I've amended your code with some debugging logs like this:

```
public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}: Application starts");

    var timeoutPolicy = TimeoutPolicy
        .TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            onTimeoutAsync: (ctx, ts, t) => {
                Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}: Timeout has occurred");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() 
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) },
            onRetryAsync: (dr, ts) => {
                Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}: Retry will be triggered");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

    var strategy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, timeoutPolicy);
    await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://httpstat.us/500");
        Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}: Response has been received");
        return response;
    }, CancellationToken.None);

    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}: Application finishes");
}
```

- It prints `Response has been received` whenever the httpClient has received a response

  - I've used `httpstat.us` only for testing purposes
- It prints `Timeout has occurred` whenever the httpClient did not receive a response under 30 seconds
- It prints `Retry will be triggered` whenever the retry policy should be fired but before the delay penalty
- It prints `Application finishes` whenever all the retries are issued and none of them succeeded or when one of the requests succeeds

With the current setup the output would look like this:

```
1: Response has been received
1: Retry will be triggered
2: Response has been received
2: Retry will be triggered
8: Response has been received
8: Retry will be triggered
18: Response has been received
18: Application finishes
```

So as you can see, we have issued 4 requests (one initial and 3 retries) without luck. But at the end the application has continued its work.